# Dynamic file mapping with relative destination

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

This is a generic question about dynamic file mapping with *Grunt.js*, but for the example purpose, I'll be trying to build **coffee** files in a project with a dynamic structure :

[image: Structure]

Here, I can have multiple (dynamic) target folders with a different depth. Finding *coffee* files remain easy, it will match `**/coffee/*.coffee` anytime.

What I'm trying to achieve, is making the ***dest*** property **relative** to the matched coffee file :

- find **`**/coffee/*.coffee`**
- compile to **`../js/*.js`**

Instead of making it relative to the project folder (Gruntfile).

```js
coffee: {
    compile: {
        files: [
            {
              expand: true,
              src: ['**/coffee/*.coffee'],
              dest: '../js/', // This won't work ! But I wish it could :)
              ext: '.js'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How would you achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's a very good idea. It sounds like each target should perhaps be a repository of its own. Even if we ignore that, you'll have other problems, such as difficulty telling target and non-target folders apart. For example, your current pattern would potentially match CoffeeScript files in the `node_modules/` directory.

I also find it weird that your targets have differing folder structures (i.e. `coffee/` and `js/` are not on the same level). Again, it sounds like they're different projects, and should have their own repos.

That being said, if you really, really have to do it like that, there are a few ways to accomplish this.

First, the "normal" way to do it would be to simply specify multiple targets manually. I'll be using the `Gruntfile.coffee` syntax here:

```
coffee:
  target1:
    expand: true
    cwd: 'target1/coffee'
    src: '**/*.coffee'
    dest: 'target1/js'
    ext: '.js'
  targetX:
    expand: true
    cwd: 'targetX/some-folder/coffee'
    src: '**/*.coffee'
    dest: 'targetX/some-folder/js'
    ext: '.js'
```

However if you're certain you need to have dynamic targets, and don't mind blacklisting unwanted folders, perhaps try something like this:

```
coffee: do ->
  targets = {}
  for target in grunt.file.expand '**/coffee', '!node_modules/**'
    targets[target.split('/', 1)[0]] =
      expand: true
      cwd: target
      src: '**/*.coffee'
      dest: target + '/../js'
      ext: '.js'
  targets
```

This will essentially do the same as the previous snippet, with some added uncertainty. You could perhaps get rid of the blacklist by having a `targets/` folder contain all the targets, and using `targets/**/coffee` as the pattern.

Alternatively you could use `grunt.file.expandMapping`:

```
coffee:
  compile:
    files: grunt.file.expandMapping ['**/coffee/**/*.coffee', '!node_modules/**'], '',
      expand: true
      ext: '.js'
      rename: (base, src) ->
        src.replace '/coffee/', '/js/'
```

While it may look kind of simple (and ugly), it's the slowest option and feels the most wrong.

So there. It's possible, but most likely not what you really want.

Comment: Thanks for this explicit answer. I totally agree with you, and this is a case very specific to our workflow when working with multi-device projects. We could make it with multiple Gruntfiles but we tend to have one file by project. Codekit has the option to replace instances of path components. This is what I was trying to reproduce. I just found the last solution myself, but finally, I think I'll follow your advices and specify targets manually. I was also curious to see how the community would achieve this. Thanks a lot @simo-kinnunen !

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious. Can you explain why the last method is slower? Surely it's going to be doing the same amount of directory searching in it's globbing as the one before it?

Comment: True, the second example is indeed not much better because it looks for 'coffee' on any level, but this could be improved relatively easily by enforcing a more strict directory layout. While I'd still recommend that the OP split his repo and avoid the issue altogether, I could _perhaps_ see myself using the second method with a cheaper glob pattern for creating dynamic targets in general. But the last one, simply no.

Comment: The second method makes it possible for watch to only trigger for specific subfolders, which would be a huge saving when there are several independent subfolders.